# A property of functions from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to prove the following:

"$\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists a $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $X=_c\mathbb{R}$ ($X,\mathbb{R}$ have the same cardinality) such that

$|f(s)-f(t)|<\epsilon$ for all $s,t\in X$."

I have no idea how to proceed.

**Thank you in advance for your time and effort.**

Comment: $$M_k = f^{-1}([k\cdot \varepsilon, (k+1)\varepsilon))\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$ at least one of the $M_k$ must have cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The countable union of the sets $M_k$ must add up to the domain of $f$ which is $\mathbb{R}$. If all $M_k$ are countable then their union ia also countable, a contradiction. Thus at least one has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. Did I got it right?

Comment: More or less. If you don't assume the continuum hypothesis, you must account also for the possibility of cardinalities between $\aleph_0$ and $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. But if $\kappa = \sup \{\operatorname{card} M_k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} < \mathfrak{c}$, then $$\mathfrak{c} = \operatorname{card} \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} M_k \leqslant \aleph_0\cdot \kappa = \kappa < \mathfrak{c},$$ a contradiction.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I may assume the continuum hypothesis. Thank you for helping out.